# Ask the system to authenticate my pattern lock

Tags: android, authentication, passwords

I'm using this pattern lock view library: https://github.com/aritraroy/PatternLockView

In complete callback of this view, i can receive a string like "845321", a md5 or sha1.

Can i use this result and request the system for authenticating the result for me using the pattern pass users have set up in their phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, sorry. The user has to authenticate with the device; you cannot supply authentication credentials on the user's behavlf.

Comment: Thank you, i have understanded.